# How to fix a left column of a manual table in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I have a manual table in LWC [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1sY5_z3a/1/edit)

I want to fix the first left column of the table, I tried cell fixed, position sticky and the below CSS but still no luck

```css
.table tr td:first-child {
      position:sticky;
      z-index: 1
}
```

Could someone please suggest how can I fix the first left column as shown in the playground? `Opportunity Name` should be fixed in the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one css selector :

```css
table tr>th:first-child
/* or .slds-table tr>th:first-child */ {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Element selector goes without prepending `.` dot sign

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.
>   You must specify a threshold with at least one of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` for sticky positioning to behave as expected. Otherwise, it will be indistinguishable from relative positioning.

[Sticky Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Sticky_positioning)

Comment: Thank you for your response it is working as expected in playground but in real time it work only on the column header not on the data below the header, and I have 2 tables on my page and the above fix first column header for both of the tables, and I need to fix only one of them, could you please suggest

Comment: Provide pls a link of playground code, then I'll be able to suggest a fix)

Comment: Playground is mention in the question but it is working fine in playground :(

Comment: Just try to make your CSS selectors more specific. For instance, add some custom class to the target table and rewrite the selector so as to apply this selector to only this table. Chrome debug inspector can help you a lot.

Comment: But it fixes only the column header not the data :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102583/discussion-between-oleh-berehovskyi-and-gs650x).